# NPM install @latest does not install latest version of package

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install, myget

I'm trying to install a package which our company built.
In *package.json* it's listed in the dependencies as:

`"package-name": "latest"`

Our current latest version is 3.5.0, which I can see when I run `npm show package-name versions`. However when I run `npm install package-name@latest`, version 3.2.3 is installed.
Before version 3.2.3, everything worked fine. It always used the latest version up until that point.

I've checked for differences between the 3.2.3 package and the 3.5.0, but I can't find any.

I tried deleting the package (including *package-lock.json*) and reinstalling it. We've also updated the package itself a couple of times, but for installing, it keeps using version 3.2.3.

We use MyGet package manager, 3.5.0 is flagged as the latest version.
How can we get `npm install` to target the correct latest version instead of the outdated one?

Comment: if you run `npm outdated` what does it says for your package?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [npm's documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/adding-dist-tags-to-packages#publishing-a-package-with-a-dist-tag):

> By default, running `npm publish` will tag your package with the `latest` dist-tag.

If you maintain older versions of this package, then version 3.2.3 may have been published after 3.5.0 along with this default dist-tag.

The [command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-install#description) `npm install package-name@latest` is actually just asking for the version with the `latest` dist-tag attached and so would install 3.2.3 rather than 3.5.0.

The [dist-tag](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-dist-tag) command can be used to set the `latest` tag against the correct version.